# Tab delimited dataset ValueError truth of array with more than one element is ambiguous error

Tags: python, numpy

I have this tab delimited dataset that looks like this:

```
PITG_00022  start_codon 262407  262409  -
PITG_00022  stop_codon  260777  260779  -
PITG_00022  exon    260867  262409  -
PITG_00022  CDS 260867  262409  -
PITG_00022  exon    260777  260826  -
PITG_00022  CDS 260780  260826  -
PITG_00023  start_codon 273160  273162  +
PITG_00023  stop_codon  274778  274780  +
PITG_00023  exon    272998  273288  +
PITG_00023  CDS 273160  273288  +
PITG_00023  exon    273368  273652  +
PITG_00023  CDS 273368  273652  +
PITG_00023  exon    273729  273788  +
PITG_00023  CDS 273729  273788  +
PITG_00023  exon    273885  273958  +
PITG_00023  CDS 273885  273958  +
PITG_00023  exon    274022  274127  +
PITG_00023  CDS 274022  274127  +
PITG_00023  exon    274194  274346  +
```

Here is my code, which was very graciously posted here [Renumbering tab delimited data in two columns relative to contents of a third column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461242/renumbering-tab-delimited-data-in-two-columns-relative-to-contents-of-a-third-co/14463536#comment20204953_14463536) I made some changes, but the error I get (see below) was present before those changes were made:

```
import numpy
import pandas
import pandas as pd
import sys

sys.stdout = open("outtry2.txt", "w")
data = pd.read_csv('pinfestans-edited2.csv', sep='\t')#,
              #converters={'STRAND': lambda s: s[0]})
groups = data.groupby(['STRAND', 'GENE_ID'])

corrected = []

for (direction, gene_name), group in groups:
    print direction,gene_name
if group.index[group.TYPE=='start_codon']:
    start_exon = group.index[group.TYPE=='exon'][0]
if direction == '+':
    group['POSA'] = 1 + abs(group.POS1 - group.POS1[start_exon])
    group['POSB'] = 1 + abs(group.POS2 - group.POS1[start_exon])
else:
    group['POSA'] = 1 - abs(group.POS2 - group.POS2[start_exon])
    group['POSB'] = 1 - abs(group.POS1 - group.POS2[start_exon])
print group
corrected.append(group)
```

Here is a sample of the output:

```
 GENE_ID     TYPE         POS1    POS2    STRAND  POSA  POSB
104  PITG_00021  start_codon  258927  258929  +       1     3   
105  PITG_00021  stop_codon   260547  260549  +       1621  1623
106  PITG_00021  exon         258927  260549  +       1     1623
107  PITG_00021  CDS          258927  260546  +       1     1620
+ PITG_00023
     GENE_ID     TYPE         POS1    POS2    STRAND  POSA  POSB
114  PITG_00023  start_codon  273160  273162  +       163   165 
115  PITG_00023  stop_codon   274778  274780  +       1781  1783
116  PITG_00023  exon         272998  273288  +       1     291 
117  PITG_00023  CDS          273160  273288  +       163   291 
118  PITG_00023  exon         273368  273652  +       371   655 
119  PITG_00023  CDS          273368  273652  +       371   655 
120  PITG_00023  exon         273729  273788  +       732   791 
121  PITG_00023  CDS          273729  273788  +       732   791 
122  PITG_00023  exon         273885  273958  +       888   961 
123  PITG_00023  CDS          273885  273958  +       888   961 
124  PITG_00023  exon         274022  274127  +       1025  1130
125  PITG_00023  CDS          274022  274127  +       1025  1130
126  PITG_00023  exon         274194  274346  +       1197  1349
```

And here is the error I get after it runs for awhile:

```
>>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\I.S\Part-2\Convert_to_exonfile.py", line 51, in <module>
if group.index[group.TYPE=='start_codon']:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>>>
```

Now I tested out a few of the calculations by hand, and it appears to be doing exactly what I want it to, except only for the genes listed with the STRAND as + (note that the PITG_00022 gene from the sample input is missing in the output). I'm thinking that it's doing the calculations for the + STRAND groups first, but then once it gets to the - STRAND groups, it gets that error. Now I read about using `any()` and `all()`, as well as a post about using `set()` in a similar array valueError thread, but I can't figure out how that would solve my problem here or how I would implement it. Appreciate any help in advance, thanks.

Comment: What's happening is that you have a `group` with more than one `start_codon`, so `group.TYPE=='start_codon'` has more than one `True` entry, and so `group.index[group.TYPE=='start_codon']` has more than one entry. You seem to only be checking that it is not an empty array, if so wrapping the whole expression inside an `any()` should do the trick. Although you may want to figure out why you are getting more than one `start_codon` and whether that makes sense.

Comment: I tried using the `any()` code, and that got rid of the error. I'm not sure what effect it had on the output though, which looks the same. I was trying have it define `start_exon` as the `exon` TYPE that appears after the `start_codon` TYPE for a given Gene_ID. So there should be only 1 `start_codon` in a group, but the dataset has thousands of genes so there are thousands of `start_codons`. I'm still not getting any of the - strand entries though. I though it was related to this error but apparently not. Thanks for your help